# How do I add load page to click function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, load

I am using the following script to close a contact panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("top-current");
        $(this).toggleClass("top");
        $("#contact").toggleClass("top-current");
        $("#contact").toggleClass("top");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

As I am using the same script on different pages, if the user is on a page other than the home page then I need to add more to the script so that the home page is loaded (index.html) after the panel has closed.  So I guess I would need a delay and then the index.html page to load, but I am not sure how to do this in jQuery, and would be grateful for some help.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that when you say you need to add a delay, what you mean is that you want to wait until the sliding animation has finished. You can provide a callback function to the [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) method which will run when the animation is complete. In that callback, you can send the user to your home page:

```
$("#panel").slideUp("slow", function() {
    window.location = "index.html";
});
```